# CDK - Add policies to role with For each

Tags: typescript, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-roles

I'm trying to create a Role with some policies, which will differ from lambda to lambda. The ideal scenario would be to have a function where the role and policies are all created and then I'd just call the function and give it the name of the role and the policies I wanted attached, and it would create all of it. So far I have this:

Usage of lambda role creation:

```
...
    const lambdarole = this.createLambdaRole( 'Test Role', [
      'KMSLambdaPolicy',
      'S3LambdaPolicy',
    ]);
...
```

Role and policies creation:

```
  private createLambdaRole(roleName: string, policyName: string[]) {
    const role = new Role(this, 'Role', {
      roleName: roleName,
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
      description: 'Role for lambda access',
      managedPolicies: [],
    });

    const kmspolicy = new ManagedPolicy(this, 'KMSLambdaPolicy', {
      managedPolicyName: 'KMSLambdaPolicy',
      statements: [
        new PolicyStatement({
          effect: Effect.ALLOW,
          actions: [
            'kms:Decrypt',
            'kms:GenerateDataKey',
            'kms:DescribeKey'],
        }),
      ],
    });

    const s3policy = new ManagedPolicy(this, 'S3LambdaPolicy', {
      managedPolicyName: 'S3LambdaPolicy',
      statements: [
        new PolicyStatement({
          effect: Effect.ALLOW,
          actions: [
            's3:PutObject',
            's3:GetObject',
            's3:GetObjectAttributes'],
          resources: ['*'],
        }),
      ],
    });

    policyName.forEach(policyName => role.addManagedPolicy(policyName));

    return role;
  }
```

Currently I can't get it to work, and it gives the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'IManagedPolicy'.

Is what I want even possible?

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help!

**SOLUTION FOUND**

I managed to make it work with the code bellow:

```
policyName.forEach(policyName => {
  const importedPolicy = ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyName(this, policyName, policyName);
  role.addManagedPolicy(importedPolicy);
});
```

**Note**: `addManagedPolicy` requires a *scope*, an *id* and a *policy name*. Since my policy ID's and names are the same, I just needed to call the array again (hence the `this, policyName, policyName`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addManagedPolicy` expects an `IManagedPolicy` object, but you provided a string instead.

```
    // the managed policy definition is only needed once for your whole account,
    // if you want to reuse it. 
    // It has to be unique if you want to map it by name.
    // the following is an example for a customer-managed policy.
    // the attribute `managedPolicyName` is the identifier for the 
    // import later on.
    const kmspolicy = new ManagedPolicy(this, 'MP-KMSLambda', {
      managedPolicyName: 'KMSLambdaPolicy'
      // etc.
    }); 


    // the following role attachment can happen everywhere in your CDK application, 
    // e.g. in another construct or stack.
    //
    // The policyNames list need to have the same identifier as in
    // your new ManagedPolicies before.
    const policyNames = ['KMSLambdaPolicy'];
    policyNames.forEach(policyName => {
       const importedPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyName(this, `${role.roleName}-${policyName}`, policyName)
       role.addManagedPolicy(importedPolicy)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried your suggestion (also removed the consts from every new policy and changed the naming of the policies) and it currently gives me this error: `Policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/Acceptance-S3LambdaPolicy-MonthlyReports does not exist or is not attachable. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity; Request ID: 90e9de14-2161-491d-ac11-ae66f9ae9a02; Proxy: null)`

Comment: Since this is a managed policy by me, should I not use `ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyName(policyName)` instead? I tried this but it requests an ID and I don't know how to get it

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I managed to fix it. For some reason I needed to delete the stack and recreate them, but it's working as intended now (updated post w/ solution). Thank you again for the help!